# How can I have relative source paths in my Vite JS CSS build output?

Tags: build, vite

Using Vite JS in its current version as my frontend build.

In my CSS / SCSS I reference sources such as fonts or images by a relative path and I'd like to keep this relative path in my build output as is and don't want it to be converted to an absolute path (which after deployment on the live system is not identical).

Extract of my file structure:

```
Images/my-sample-image.jpg
Scss/style.scss
JavaScript/main.js //(also my entry point in viteconfig.js /  input)
```

In my main.js I do import my Scss/style.scss

Im my scss I reference a backgound image by `url('../Images/my-sample-image.jpg')`

After build in my CSS file the it gets converted to `url('./my-sample-image.jpg)` in case I leave base empty in my viteconfig.
If I don't set it at all I get:
`url('/my-sample-image.jpg)`

What I expect or wish to have:

`url('../Images/my-sample-image.jpg)`

As said I have tested various viteconfig "base" options for example: `base: ''` or base: `'./'` without any success yet.

I am using a build.rollupOptions.output path, but with or without it does not seem to have any effect.

If I knew the absolute path where my App is beeing uses I could get a long with absolute paths in my CSS and this works fine, but this in unfortunately not the case here.

Would be happy to get some tips how I can get this done.

Cheers
Michael